# Hibernate generates ambiguous SQL query

Tags: java, hibernate

Consider the following **ParentClass** entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "iwrs")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class ParentClass {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PK_IWRS")
    public int id;

    public String name;

    public ParentClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And the following **ChildClass** entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "iwrs")
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=ParentClass.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    private ParentClass parent;

    public ChildClass(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

As you can see, this ChildClass extends from ParentClass. Moreover, it contains a reference for ParentClass mapped in **parent** field.

There is a point where I want to get all instances of ParentClass, but not the instances that are ChildClass.

I searched around and found that could be achieved with this criteria:

```
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria(ParentClass.class, "parentClass")
                .add(Restrictions.eq("class", ParentClass.class));
```

However, when I try to list it, I get the following error:

> ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:147 - ERROR: column reference "clazz_" is
>   ambiguous

If I remove the last line of the criteria, the query is successfully executed. But the ChildClass instances are also returned, which is not what I want.

Here is the query generated by hibernate when I have all the restrictions:

> select this_.id as id1_29_1_, this_.name as name2_29_1_,
>   this_.parent_id as parent_i1_14_1_, this_.clazz_ as clazz_1_,
>   parentclas2_.id as id1_29_0_, parentclas2_.name as name2_29_0_,
>   parentclas2_.parent_id as parent_i1_14_0_, parentclas2_.clazz_ as
>   clazz_0_ from ( select id, name, null::int4 as parent_id, 0 as clazz_
>   from iwrs.parent_class union all select id, name, parent_id, 1 as
>   clazz_ from iwrs.child_class ) this_ left outer join ( select id,
>   name, null::int4 as parent_id, 0 as clazz_ from iwrs.parent_class
>   union all select id, name, parent_id, 1 as clazz_ from
>   iwrs.child_class ) parentclas2_ on this_.parent_id=parentclas2_.id
>   where clazz_=?

Working example available here: https://github.com/mmalmeida/hibernateTest , just run the test RetrieveParentTest.java.

Do you know how I can work around this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try using the alias you defined:

```
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                    .createCriteria(ParentClass.class, "parentClass")
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("parentClass.class", ParentClass.class));
```

Comment: Hey malvarez, thanks for your input. Unfortunately, it gives the same error. I also checked the query that is generated by hibernate and it is exactly the same in both cases.

Comment: I am sorry that it didn't work. Can you update your question with the query that Hibernate is generating?

Comment: Sure, will do that ;)

Comment: Added. If you have any idea please let me know.

Comment: @micdcar, I cannot find the error. I googled a bit and find a lot of questions about the same problem. I'll try later and I'll let you know if a find something

Comment: @malvarez I created a working example at https://github.com/mmalmeida/hibernateTest (see class RetrieveParentTest)

Comment: Hi @micdcar, I download the code and ran it but I see that it's configured to run on PostgreSQL. I didn't have a working version of that database now. So, I'll try later configuring an in-memory database. I have no time right now  but I'll do my best when I can. If you want, you can download the Hibernate's source code to attach it to your IDE so that you can debug what Hibernate is doing. I've done that a couple of times.

Comment: @malvarez you just need to change the c3p0 datasource in https://github.com/mmalmeida/hibernateTest/blob/master/src/main/resources/spring-SF-tests.xml to use an in-memory db